# Display off and lock

Tags: lock-screen, display

I recently switched from Android to Windows Phone 8 (Nokia Lumia 520). Is there an app that I can use to turn off the display and lock the phone? I would at least like something that turns off the display. I do not have double tap to wake feature or face down to turn display off on the Lumia 520.

Any ideas?

Clarification: I am looking for an app (which can be used as a live tile), which when clicked, will turn off the display. I want to skip using the power button.

Comment: I didn't understand what you really want. To me you are describing the power button. Or the setting that turn the display and lock the phone after X seconds.

Comment: If you want timed locking you can set it via `lock screen setting` or if you want just lock, lock (hardware) button there. Double tap feature is not yet available in all phones and it's face down to silent not display off.

Comment: There is an app called [QUICK CONTROLS](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quick-controls/843d2576-3900-46e0-a4df-83a0440ead63)

Answer (score 2):

To me you are describing the power button that turns off the screen.

if you go to lockscreen settings: **Settings -> lock screen** you can set 2 things:

**Screen times out after:**

- 30 seconds
- 1 minute
- to 15 minutes

this is the time the screen will turn off automatically when not used.

the 2nd option is:

**Require a password after:**

- each time
- 30 seconds
- 1 minute
- to 15 minutes (which is the default)

if you want to have to enter your password each time you turn on your screen you have to put the last setting to each time.

Comment: I am looking for an app which turns off the display.

Comment: @Castor What's the difference in use an app or the built-in settings?

Comment: @castor there is a dedicated button for that.. why need an app as well?

Comment: This doesn't answer his question at all which is he is looking for a software lock and unlock button. (The latter part is available with the "double tap to wake" feature in Windows Phone).

Comment: @GeertvdC touching an icon on the screen is much easier than pressing the power button. On Android there's lots of softwares can do that and most of my friends hardly use the power button anymore

Answer (score 1):

This type of app cannot be made for [Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341134/turn-off-screen-from-inside-app-in-windows-phone-7), the api's do not exist, and if someone found a workaround it would be removed from the store.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is available. Just go to the store and download the [One Touch Lock Screen app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/one-touch-lockscreen/a3b1220b-1f9a-4bf0-93bc-21ed02792279). This is a free app that I used when I broke my lock button.

Answer (score 0):

He is asking for that app means, he is thinking for future, how many times you press the lock button  which is inbuilt, one or other day it will not work, what will you do then.. to overcome this, in andriod there is an app for screen lock and off, similarly he is expecting this app in windows phone..

mr. castro unfortunately non of the developers have developed such app for windows.. thinking of some one will workout for it..

Answer (score 0):

The question asked is:
I want an app that turns off the screen, but is still listening for touch events, so that I can double tap it again to bring the phone back on (and quit the app that was listening).  This is to emulate the double tap to wake feature.

My answer:

Perhaps there's an app that just turns the screen black and hopefully uses very little power. This app (a black screen) can then be listening for a double touch event.  But then other buttons on the phone will still be active though.  And it won't be what you really want which is a true turn-off-screen-but-still-listen-for-touch-events app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are only side keys release apps available for WP8. Here are their links:

[Power Tiles](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=bb1206f6-1ff4-4c05-a757-c5cbcbcf715a)
[Lock Screen](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=f93c89f3-2136-4640-8f58-ecf86aba05b9)

Awaiting a similar ones for WP7.

Answer (score -1):

Download System Tiles. It's an app that will allow you to pin the "lock screen" tile on your home page. So, you can double-tap to wake up your phone then use the "lock screen" tile to lock your phone. Hope it helps!

Comment: this pins the Lock Screen settings.